# Media query not working with background images

Tags: html, css, media-queries, background-image

I have a div on my website with the following styles:

```
#image {
    background-image: url(../Images/logo.png);
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 80px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
```

It's actually the company logo. I want to change this logo for smaller screen sizes so I made the following media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
    #image {
        background-image: url(../Images/logoImage%20copy.jpg); 
        width: 88px; 
    }
}
```

But the Image was still not changing. I then added !important:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
    #image {
        background-image: url(../Images/logoImage%20copy.jpg); !important
        width: 88px; !important
    }
}
```

But it is still not changing the background image.

**The media query is working finely except for this (as other properties are working)**

I am also including the html code:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
    #image {
        background-image: url(http://placehold.it/80x88); !important
        width: 88px; !important
    }
}

#image {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x80);
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 80px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
    <!--Some Code-->
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML code so I can try and reproduce your issue?

Comment: @itsanewabstract I have added sample html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this. The media query should be below the default rule so it can override it properly.

On other hand, the `!important` goes before the `;` not after, but is not needed, at least for this snippet.

Last, the code snippet won't work properly in the snippet preview with 930px as media query breakpoint because the snippet is shown in a iframe and its viewport is less than 930px so default rule will always be overriden by the media query in the snippet preview. To avoid this see the snippet in a blank page by clicking Expand snippet.

```css
#image {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x80);
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 80px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
    #image {
        background-image: url(http://placehold.it/80x88);
        width: 88px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
    <!--Some Code-->
```